# Rating for the teacher doesn't show up after the user logged in and rated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails project, a user can only rate his teacher if he already signed up and logged in. However, after the user logged in and rated the teacher, I couldn't see his rating. I don't know what cause the problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is my **ratings_controller.rb**:

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :get_teacher

  def new
    get_teacher
    @rating = current_user.ratings.build
  end

  def create
    get_teacher
    @rating = current_user.ratings.create(rating_params)
    if @rating.save
      redirect_to school_teacher_path(@teacher.school, @teacher)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    get_teacher
    @rating = @teacher.ratings.find(params[:id])
    @rating.destroy

    redirect_to school_teacher_path(@teacher.school, @teacher)
  end

  def get_teacher
    @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
  end

  private

    def rating_params
      params.require(:rating).permit(:easiness, :helpfulness, :clarity, :comment,
      :teacher_id, :school_id)
    end
end
```

**teachers/show.html.erb**:

```
<!-- Caculate the average rating of the teacher -->
<h1>Average ratings:</h1>
<p>Clarity:
  <%= @teacher.ratings.average(:clarity) %>
</p>
<p>Easiness:
  <%= @teacher.ratings.average(:easiness) %>
</p>
<p>Helpfulness:
  <%= @teacher.ratings.average(:helpfulness) %>
</p>
<hr>

<!-- Show all the ratings -->
<h2>All the ratings:</h2>
<div>
  <%= @teacher.ratings.each do |rating| %>

    <p>Clarity:
      <%= rating.clarity %>
    </p>

    <p>Helpfulness:
      <%= rating.helpfulness %>
    </p>

    <p>Easiness:
      <%= rating.easiness %>
    </p>

    <p>Comment:
      <%= rating.comment %>
    </p>

    <%= link_to "Delete rating", [rating.teacher, rating], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-warning" %>

    <hr>
  <% end %>
</div>

<p>
  <%= link_to "Rate teacher", new_teacher_rating_path(@teacher), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to "Back to school", school_path(@school), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</p>
```

**ratings/new.html.erb**:

```
<h1>Teacher Rating</h1>
<%= form_for([@teacher, @rating]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :clarity %>
    <%= f.text_field :clarity %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :easiness %>
    <%= f.text_field :easiness %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :helpfulness %>
    <%= f.text_field :helpfulness %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :comment %>
    <br>
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**rating.rb**:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :teachers
end
```

**teacher.rb**:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users

  def name
    "#{firstName} #{middleName} #{lastName}"
  end

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity of my question. Basically, now a user can log in and rate the teacher. However, the problem is the rating just doesn't show up. Hopefully, this will clear the confusion of my question.

Comment: do you get any exception?

Comment: @tokhi, No, I don't get any exception. And, I've just posted my model files. Could you please take a look at them? Sorry for the late answer, I was busy with my main job.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is rating, not associated with user. You can use build method, it will add user_id to rating automatically,

```
@rating = current_user.ratings.build(rating_params)
```

and you not associating teacher id,

```
@rating.teacher_id = @teacher.id
```

And your the relation between user and teacher, both has has_many it's incorrect syntax, you should use has_and_belongs_to_many. I'm not sure about your database schema, If you have ratings as relation in between user and teachers you can use 'has_many through:', as suggested below

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :teachers, through: :ratings
end
```

teacher.rb:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :ratings

  def name
    "#{firstName} #{middleName} #{lastName}"
  end

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I believe I already had that line of code in my ratings_controller.rb

Comment: Hi, Nope, You have used create method instead of build in rating.

Comment: I tried edit it to build, but it still doesn't work. Do you need to see my other files too?

Comment: I found that you not associating teacher with the rating, you should add it before saving it. If this not working post your model class.

Comment: I've just updated the files as you requested. Could you please take a look? I was busy with my main job, so sorry for the late answer.

Comment: Hi, you can't use has_many relation in both users and teachers. If you wan't many to many relation, you should use as_and_belongs_to_many on both of these models. But as you have rating in middle of user and teachers, I suggest you to have has_many through, pls check this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association Let me know if you can't fix yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I quite don't understand what you really mean. Could you please explain it more in details?

Comment: I tried to update my model associations as you suggested but the problem is still there. :(